# $(n^{k})$ diverges whenever k is positive.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergence-operator

Is it true that the sequence $(n^{k})$ diverges for $k$ a fixed positive?

You should be able to prove this simply by showing that the sequence is not bounded, correct?

I just want to make sure that I'm not missing something.

Comment: Correct.  (Assuming the parens don't stand for some special function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  and you can show it's not bounded,  given a positive number $M$,  any $n>M^{1/k}$ will give an output higher than $M$, since $x^k$ is monotonically increasing when $k>0$

(this is assuming k is fixed and it's a limit as n goes to infinity)